# Magento - Sort Products in Cart in Alphabetical Order

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shopping-cart, sorting

How can I sort the products in the cart in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> magento\app\design\frontend\theme\theme\template\checkout\cart.phtml

Replace

```
foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
```

With

```
$cartitems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
->setQuote($this->getQuote())
->addFieldToSelect('name')
->addOrder('name', 'asc');

$items = array();
foreach ($cartitems as $item) {
if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
$items[] = $item;
}
}
```

I think you will need to customize the code a bit.

Or another solution may be :

> magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php

Update line : `$this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();`

To

```
 $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->setOrder('name','asc');
```

I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Thank you, I found a similar code to this but can't get it to work. It comes up with an error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH in ..../checkout/cart.phtml on line 143

I presume i'm leaving behind the <?php   and   ?> before / after it?

Comment: This is what my code looks like which gives me an error message;

                <tbody>
                <?php $cartitems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
->setQuote($this->getQuote())
->addFieldToSelect('name')
->addOrder('name', 'asc');

$items = array();
foreach ($cartitems as $item) {
if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
$items[] = $item;
}
} ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>

Comment: Even if this works, the cart is already slow so I don't think there is a need for an additional query to retrieve the items that are already retrieved by `getItems`. I think a better approach would be just to use the results of `getItems` loop through them and order by name.

Comment: Marius, can you explain a little more about you idea of looping through them and order by name? Sorry, real novice here!

Comment: Updated my answer may be that can help

Comment: @user3217495. See what obscure wrote in the other answer. Basically `getItems` will give you a collection of cart items. You can loop through them using `foreach` and build an array of items, then sort that array by name. You can get the name by using `$item->getName()`

Comment: I did not checked that answer actually!

Comment: Thank you all. TBI Infotech; I tried the update on the 'quote.php' page too and that didn't work. Will try what obscure and Marius recommend. Will keep you all posted - thank you!

Comment: @TBIInfotech - I take it back; I had tried ones very similar to your last edit that didn't work, but, yours did the trick!!! Thank you!!!!! So happy that it's now working! Just hoping there's no gliches with this method :)

Comment: This answer suggests overwriting something in the core of Magento. You should NEVER do this, because it will break whenever you upgrade Magento. The answer by obscure is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Extend class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` and override method `getItems`.
It returns an array of items that contains objects of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`.
You could use `$_item->getName()` to access the product name.
Sort the array of objects.

**Edit:**

**Quick:**
Copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/cart.phtml` to `app/frontend/[mypackage]/[my_current_store_theme]/checkout/cart.phtml`
In the first lines place your code:

```
 $myItems = $this->getItems();
 // sort $myItems
 ...
```

Replace bellow in same file:

```
<?php /* foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): */ ?>
<?php /* with: */ ?>
<?php foreach($myItems as $_item): ?>
```

**Magento way:**
Create a custom module after reading a tutorial about how to (there are plenty).
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/
Here there is a nice documentation that explains in detail how to create an extension: **Extension Developer's** (including module). http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf

Or use an extension for module creation:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html
I would read first the tutorial if I would be new to Magento.

You'll need to overwrite the class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart`. First declare module's config.xml and rewrite the block class. You're telling `Magento` to use your class instead of the class from core. Don't forget to declare the module in app/etc/modules/Mynamespace_Mymodule.xml too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mynamespace_Mymodule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mynamespace_Mymodule>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <mymodule> <!-- or <mymodule_something>-->
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mymodule>

        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Cart</cart>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>

    <helpers> <!-- You need this too: A declared class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Data in Helper dir in current module -->
        <mymodule> <!-- or <mymodule_something> to Mage::helper('mymodule_something/data') instead of Mage::helper('mymodule/data') -->
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
        </mymodule>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

In `app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Cart.php`:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        $items = parent::getItems();

        /* Here you sort $items in alphabetic order.
           Maybe with usort php function ?
           Or with array_multisort:
        */
        $a = array();
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
            $a[$key] = $item->getName();
        }
        array_multisort($a, $items);

        return $items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I change all this, sorry?

Comment: You create a new local module and extend the class block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart`. There are tutorials for this.

Comment: Still don't get what i'm really doing. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I edit the answer.

Comment: Here is another extension for products sorting, You can sort product using multiple filters.
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/improve-catalog-sorting-products-extension.html